# 404 file not found in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter MVC. My home view is loaded correctly. When i replace home in index() with aboutus it is working, but when i call aboutus function then it is showing 404 file not found error. Login is also working correctly. I am not getting what is wrong. My view folder contains aboutus, home and login files.

```
public function index()
    {

    $this->load->view("home"); 

}
    function login()
{

    $this->load->view("login"); 

}
function aboutus()
{

    $this->load->view("aboutus"); 

}
```

//Here the html code

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/login">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/aboutus" >About Us</a></li>
```

Comment: Read this http://w3code.in/2015/10/codeigniter-installation-beginner-guide/

Comment: Please check that view file `aboutus.php` lies is the same folder as `login.php` and `home.php`, that is `application/views`.

Answer (score 1):

**How to load default controller**

In `config/routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = "controller_name; //this load index() in provided controller
$route['default_controller'] = "controller_name/method_name"; //this load method which you created inside provided controller(ex: main/about_us)
```

---

**How to create controller**

Path - `application/controllers/`
File name - `main.php`
inside `main.php`

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view("home"); 
    }

    function login()
    {
        $this->load->view("login"); 
    }

    function aboutus()
    {
        $this->load->view("aboutus"); 
    }

}
```

---

**How to create view**

```
Path - `application/view/`
File name - `home.php`
File name - `login.php`
File name - `aboutus.php`
```

---

**How to use Link**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>main/home">Home</a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>main/login">Login</a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>main/aboutus">aboutus</a>
```

---

**How to use `base_url()`**

in `config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

in `config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your html like this

```
<a href="<?php echos site_url('controllerName/yourfunction');?>">home</a>
<a href="<?php echos site_url('controllerName/aboutus');?>">about us</a>
```

Comment: Your said syntax is correct, but, it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add route to your new function aboutus() in routes.php

You can find routes.php in "application/config/". 
suppose your controller name is  **'Client_home'**
Then,
eg : `$route['default_controller'] = 'Client_home';`

This is the reason why aboutus is working when you replace home in index() with aboutus . The index() method will be called by default, if you are not specifying which function you want to initiate.

For the aboutus() method / function, the route will be like this : 
eg : `$route['aboutus'] = "Client_home/aboutus";`

Synatx:

```
$route['url'] = "controllername/method or function name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Example for this question. Hope this help you:

```
http://localhost/ciexample/index.php/your_controller/your_function
```

Answer (score 0):

i would like to know the controller name and also would like to know where u have change its configuration , if yes than which config .

use this in address  bar 
"localhost/folder_name_of_the_project/index/controller_name"